# embedded Linux suspend/resume reference power manager

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, power-management, powermanager

I'm currently implementing suspend/resume for embedded Linux on some non-android network device.
The requirement is to implement a sleep manager task in kernel which would trigger system suspend in case that no task is currently running and there's no traffic pending.
I guess there should be some similar implementation existing already but failed to find.
Can anyone refer me to some kind of similar project on this subject?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind doing some porting, the [wakelocks](http://lwn.net/Articles/318611/) from the Android kernel is exactly what you seem to need. User space acquires a wakelock when it needs to remain active (e.g. a task is running or traffic is taking place) and releases it when it doesn't anymore. When the number of held wakelocks reaches zero, the kernel enters suspend mode.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at this framework. Also in addition I still have to monitor input/output traffic as it is a network device